# how would one integrate the formula for the surface area of a sphere

Tags: calculus

if the equation for a sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2=r$ how would one integrate this to find the surface área. or also a sphere can be created by rotatating $x^2+y^2=r^2$ by $2(pi)$
can someone please explain how would finds these equations using calclus (im guessing specifically integrals)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n(r)$ and $V_n(r)$ the surface area and the volume enclosed by $x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2=r^2$.
For starters, we have $V_n(r) = r^n V_n(1)$ and $A_n(r)=r^{n-1}A_n(1)$.
Additionally, $A_n(r)=\frac{d}{dr} V_n(r)$, hence $A_n(1)=n V_n(1)$.
By Fubini's theorem,
$$ I_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left[-\left(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2\right)\right]\,dx =\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\,du\right)^n = \pi^{n/2}.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, by Cavalieri's principle,
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}A_n(r) e^{-r^2}\,dr = A_n(1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}r^{n-1}e^{-r^2}\,dr = A_n(1)\cdot \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}v^{n/2-1}e^{-v}\,dv \tag{2} $$
hence it follows that:
$$ A_n(1)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)},\qquad V_n(1) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}.\tag{3}$$
If $n=3$, then $A_n(1)=4\pi$ and $V_n(1)=\frac{4\pi}{3}.$